# Dynamic Environment mapping from camera in Augmented Reality setting

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am trying to implement something like [the technique described in this (old) paper](http://www.ic-at.org/papers/2004/S9-2.pdf) to use the phone camera's video frames to create an illusion of environment mapping in an AR app.

I want to take the camera frame, divide it into sub-areas and then use those as faces on the cube map. The division of the camera frame would look something like this:

[image: image from the cited paper]

Now the X area is easy, I can use glCopyTexImage2D to copy that square area to my cubemap texture. But I need help with the trapezoid shaped areas around X (forget about the trianlges for now).

How can I take those trapezoidal areas and distort them into square textures? I think I need the opposite transformation of the later occurring perspective projection, so that the two will cancel each other out in the final render if I render the cubemap as a skybox around my camera (does that explain what I want?).

Before doing this I tried a simpler step of putting the square X area on every side of the cubemap just to see if glCopyTexImage2D can even be used for this. It can, but the results are not rotated right, some faces are "upside down" when I render the cubemap as a skybox. The question is similar: How can I rotate them before using them as textures?

I also thought about solving the problem from the other side and modifying the "texture coordinates" to make the necessary adjustments, but that also does not seem easy since the lookup in the fragment shader with "textureCube" is more complicated than a normal texture lookup.

Any ideas?

I'm trying to do this in my AR app on Android with OpenGL ES 2.0 but I guess more general OpenGL advice might also be useful.

**Update**

I have come to the conclusion that this is not worth pursuing anymore. The paper makes it look nice, but my experiments with a phone camera have shown a major contradiction. If you want to reflect the environment in an object rendered in AR, the camera view is very limited. When the camera is far away from the tracked object you have enough environment information for a good reflection, but you will barely see it because the camera is far away. But when you bring the camera closer to see the awesome reflection in detail, the tracked object will fill most of the camera's field of view and you barely have any environment to reflect anymore. So in either case you lose and the result is not worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need to create mesh with UV mapping described in article and render it with texture from camera to another texture. Then use it as cubemap.

Comment: thanks for providing me with an idea of something that should actually work. somehow I wasn't able to think of this myself. however, it sounds really expensive as this would need to be done for every frame.